# Estimating Time-Varying Effects of Time-Invariant Covariates

Tags: regression, semiparametric

In short, I have a time-invariant variable that I know has a time-varying effect on my outcomes of interest. I would like to estimate a plot this effect over time. What are some ways of going about this?

To give an a slightly inaccurate example, suppose we take education as this time invariant variable. However, suppose that as the individual grows older the impact of this fixed amount of education declines. How would one estimate this declining effect on the earnings of the individuals? Keep in mind that this is just an imagined scenario. In the end, I would like to be able to plot (at means) the marginal effect over time.

I thought one could so this using some sort of exponential regression or using a semi-parametric approach, but other suggestions could be appreciated too.

Comment: I suppose you could interact education with age if education and age are both independent variables (in your hypothetical, I don't think you explicitly stated an outcome of interest). If education is your dependent variable, perhaps you could specify a polynomial transformation of age to model a curvilinear relationship. As for plotting, {marginaleffects} in R should have support for making the plots that I believe you are referencing.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I hastily dismissed it on the whim that the marginal effect would be beta*age, which is a function of age but not decreasing as expected. I see now that if you know the coefficient on the time invariant variable you have all you need since the beta on the interaction term would simply be negative. Perhaps then some kind of correlated random effects model or just plain random effects could work. Thanks!